# Angular progmatically empty an input with Bootstrap typeahead

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using a form to add elements to list that is displayed on the side of the form. Markup is:

```
<form name="stateForm">
  <input type="text" ng-model="model.name" typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue">
  <button ng-click="addState(model)">Add to list</button>
</form>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="state in selected_states">{{state.name}} - {{state.desc}}</li>
</ul>
```

while the controller is:

```
  $scope.states = ['Alabama', 'Wyoming'];
  $scope.selected_states = [];
  $scope.addState = function(state){
    $scope.selected_states.push(state);
    $scope.model = {};
    $scope.stateForm.$setPristine();        
  }
```

Working sample: http://plnkr.co/edit/sLQCCm?p=preview

Now the problem is that while I can clear every input with `$scope.model={}` or `$scope.stateForm.$setPristine()`, nothing clears the input with the typeahead. I suspect this may be because of the way the typeahead directive was implemented.

Is there a way I can achieve this without ditching the typeahead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there was a bug in the `typeahead` directive that was preventing your scenario from working correctly. It was already fixed in master and will be part of the next release (0.5.0), hopefully in the coming week.

In the meantime you can grab the latest version from the CI server as shown in this plunk:
http://plnkr.co/edit/j9undd?p=preview